# Tensorflow - no module named 'embeddings' in tensorflow.models.embeddings

Tags: python, word2vec, tensorflow

I am trying to run the vector representations of words tutorial using Tensorflow found here:

http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec/index.md

The first script, word2vec_basic.py, runs fine, but the second one (found here)

https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py

gives me the error "ImportError: No module named embedding" at line 28. I installed tensorflow as per the instructions on the page, any reason why I wouldn't have gotten the embeddings module, containing word2vec?

Comment: I can confirm that on a Mac, at least, tensorflow.models only has submodules image and rnn, and no embedding. I'm not seeing an obvious build error causing this.

Comment: maybe I should be building from source, or waiting for a future release of tensorflow? Only thoughts at this point. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the more full-featured versions of word2vec such as word2vec.py require building from source.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but could you clarify what exactly one needs to build from source? My tensorflow installation is built from source, but it still doesn't include the `embeddings` module